# Is there a different way I should be naming my Laravel routes?

Tags: laravel

I currently have these routes in my API:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    Route::get('feed', [FeedController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('feed/{page}', [FeedController::class, 'index']);
});
```

I wanted to create another route that looked like this, only protected by some middleware:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function() {
    Route::get('feed/following', [FeedController::class, 'following']);
    Route::get('feed/following/{page}', [FeedController::class, 'following']);
});
```

However, it appears that the `v1/feed/following` route is actually being routed to the `v1/feed/{page}` route.

Is there a way to fix this without my route names?

Comment: re order the routes so `get('feed/{page}'` is declared after `get('feed/following/{page}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce another group in your `v1` Api path and set `feed/following` before `feed/{page}`:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    Route::group(function() {
        Route::get('feed/following', [FeedController::class, 'following']);
        Route::get('feed/following/{page}', [FeedController::class, 'following']);
    })->middleware('jwt.verify');

    Route::get('feed', [FeedController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('feed/{page}', [FeedController::class, 'show']);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The rule for `'feed/{page}'` will also match `'feed/following'`, you will wind up with page = following

Maybe create the route for `'feed/following'` before the route for `'feed/{page}'`